# I asked the wrong question and got the right answer. What now?

Tags: discussion

I asked [How do I design a triac rms power limiter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/how-do-i-design-a-triac-rms-power-limitter#comment105572_55871). **Dave Tweed** answered, in a comment, something that solved my problem. What now? Should I reform the question to make the answer a direct answer to the question. Should I ask Dave to repost his thoughts as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Yep. Think about helping those that come after you. If you can clarify things for them, then everyone will be happier. Perhaps you can add it as an edit below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say yes and yes. Alternately, if that doesn't work, re-edit your question to make the answer more relevant, and answer it yourself when it's available to do so, mentioning dave's answer. I've done things where I've answered my own question by referencing the comment, HOW it helped, and the outcome that resulted.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the primary interface to StackExchange questions is Google. Given that you've accepted Dave Tweed's answer, if I were to Google search for the original question you asked and the result was not helpful to me, there is a problem. Rephrase the question such that the accepted answer answers the question of someone finding the question via Google.